# deciding for a cleaner solution on how to use set and shift

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I want to list all the days of the week en English and French (see the sample picture below) but I'm finding myself writing some complex syntax for an even simple problem.

Is there a cleaner and better solution for this situation?

here is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

en_weeks='mon tue wed thu fri sat sun'

fr_weeks='lun mar mer jeu ven sam dim'

for i in $(seq 0 6)
do
    set $en_weeks
    shift $i
    echo -n "$1 "
    set $fr_weeks
    shift $i
    echo $1
done
```

here is the output of the script:

[image: sample output]

Comment: maybe it's not perfect but it looks pretty small, clean and understandable to me. There's nothing wrong with that code, moreover the task of printing stuff from two lists is a very simple one. So in my opinion it's not worth it to loose time on a completed , low interest task. Move on :)

Comment: that's exactly what i'm trying to do @JoulinRouge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) POSIX, no *bash*isms:

```
en_weeks="mon tue wed thu fri sat sun"
fr_weeks="lun mar mer jeu ven sam dim"
echo $fr_weeks | tr ' ' '\n'  | \
for i in $en_weeks ; do read x ; echo $i $x ; done
```

No **seq** needed, one list is itemized directly via **for**, and an in-loop **read** gets the other list -- pipes to **for** loops work just like pipes to **while** loops.

2) Very short, using BSD reshape util **rs** to transpose data:

```
echo -e $fr_weeks'\n'$en_weeks | rs -T
```

Comment: ty for the first snippet, it was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

For the English names only:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

weeks=(mon tue wed thu fri sat sun)

for i in {0..6}; do
    echo "${weeks[$i]}"
done
```

I'm using an array, since it is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want an easier way to do the same thing or if you *need* to use set/shift...

Since you are using bash, I would take advantage of the bashisms and go with:

```
en_weeks=(mon tue wed thu fri sat sun)
fr_weeks=(lun mar mer jeu ven sam dim)

for i in {0..6}
do
  echo ${en_weeks[$i]} ${fr_weeks[$i]}
done
```